# Encaps string in flow

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

I created this flow demo - https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzAEEwBeMACgEMN8BLHAFQE8AHAUwC4wCAnO7AHMAlGQB8YAOQBhAPIBVAHKMAogCUA+pLABqMDXpM27MMGDFaDbCw4AFXuyh0AHu17oseQgCEYVABZkxAAGAEZ+-sEA3EA

I am using React Native and Flow.

My code is:

```
const A = (actionType: string) => 'COUNTER_' + actionType // ActionTypePrefixer
const UP = A`UP`;
```

My goal is to call a function with backticks.Flow highlights this as an error saying:

Is there any way to do encaps with:

> [flow] array (This type is incompatible with the expected param
>   type of string See also: encaps tag)

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Flow highlights this as an error

That's because it is an error! The first parameter to a template literal function is an `Array<string>`, not a `string`. Your code would still execute because `['foo'].toString() === 'foo'`, but it would easily break in the general case. Therefor you should change

```
const A = (actionType: string) => 'COUNTER_' + actionType;
```

to

```
const A = (actionType: Array<string>) => 'COUNTER_' + actionType[0];
```

Potentially it might also be good to throw an exception if `actionType.length > 1`.